# How to update a Identi.ca from Twitter

Tags: twitter, social-networking, statusnet

There is an "out-of-the-box" way to update Twitter from Identi.ca.

But, is there any solution for update Identi.ca status from Twitter ?

If I use:

- twitterfeed.com
- http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/llaumgui.rss&trim_user=true
  I have a unsightly "llaumgui:" before each Twitt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my answer:

> [How To Remove Your Twitter Username From The RSS Feed](http://socialmediaseo.net/2010/01/16/how-to-remove-your-twitter-username-from-the-rss-feed/)

1. Use `pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=zncl_xDx2xGVxuG5p2IyXQ` to remove your username from RSS feed
2. Use the twitterfeed.com service